# What is the use of : in Dart function?

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I am testing some Flutter application and encounter : in a Dart Function, What is it used for?

I found it in Firebase for Flutter tutorial. I tried to search it in google, but can't find anything.

```
class Record {
  final String name;
  final int votes;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['votes'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        votes = map['votes'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

The Result is working fine, i just want to know what is the : used for.

Comment: see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got from https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour, section Constructor:

1. Superclass

> Specify the superclass constructor after a colon (:), just before the constructor body (if any).

```
class Employee extends Person {
  Employee() : super.fromJson(getDefaultData());
  // ···
}
```

2. Instance variables

> Besides invoking a superclass constructor, you can also initialize instance variables before the constructor body runs. Separate initializers with commas.

```
// Initializer list sets instance variables before
// the constructor body runs.
Point.fromJson(Map<String, num> json)
    : x = json['x'],
      y = json['y'] {
  print('In Point.fromJson(): ($x, $y)');
}
```

**Your example:**

So in your case the `fromMap`-Method does some assertions (before running the constructor) and assigns the variables `name` and `vote`. As these variables are final, they have to be assigned before initializing a record instance!

`fromSnapshot` just uses `fromMap` as super constructor.