# What is the benefit of the syntax for this constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

Different constructors in dart + flutter.

Following this [page](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) I am not sure I understood all there is to constructors

It seems that the only benefit of having this is only syntax sugar:

```
class Foo {
  bool something;

  Foo(this.something);
}
```

over:

```
class Foo {
  bool something;

  Foo(bool something): this.something = something;
}
```

or even curly brackets:

```
class Foo {
   bool something;

   Foo(bool something) { 
      this.something = something;
   };
}
```

Unless you want to use **final** and then you would go for the 1st or 2nd option.

So are these only syntactically different implementations of the same thing or do they bring value.

Currently I use the

**1st** (+ final fields) by default,

the **2nd** one for Null coalescing (or some small checks)

and the **3rd** one for starting services based on "post init" stuff

It just seems that I can use the **3rd** option to replace the others without any consequence (unless for final fields + const constructors). 
Is this correct? (maybe one of these is actually faster due to less instructions when compiling to asm)

**Is there any benefit for avoiding the constructor body (or the other way around)?**

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What benefits brings one constructor over another?

Comment: That question here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617729/what-is-the-use-of-in-dart-function/56617838#56617838